# How to access the sorted rows in an Angular UI Grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angular-ui-grid

I am using the [Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info) to display some data. Sorting is enabled and initialized as well as selecting a single row:

```js
vm.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    multiSelect: false,
    noUnselect: true,
    columnDefs: [
        { name: '#', field: 'ID' },
        { name: 'Name', field: 'CODE', sort: { direction: 'asc', priority: 1 } },
        { name: 'Comment', field: 'DESCR' },
    ],
    data: []
};
```

I am able to select a row and the rows are sorted by the "Name" column in ascending order as configured.

As shown in the [UI Grid Tutorial 210](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection), I have added logic to automatically select the first item after my data has been loaded and added to the grid:

```
datacontext.getAllGcTab(vm.filter).then(function (result) {
    vm.gridOptions.data = result.results;
    vm.gridApi.selection.selectRow(vm.gridOptions.data[0]);
});
```

But this code is selecting the **first item of the unsorted data**. There are about 500 items in my grid, which is not much and performs well, but in this case the selected item is somewhere down the line and invisible.

Is there any option to directly access the rows or the sorted data of the UI Grid?

I know that external sorting could solve that problem, because then I would assign the already sorted data to the grid. But this seems to me like an unnecessary overhead...

Comment: There is a fix for this on the way - I will post an answer once this has been released.

Comment: any word on the answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows()` returns an array of rows in the current sort/filter order.

Comment: If it only returns the actual visible rows, it won't do any good. It is unlikely that all 500 rows is visible at the same time.

Comment: It returns the whole dataset, I have just checked it: 
`$scope.gridOptions.data.length` returns the same value as `$scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows().length` .
http://i.imgur.com/42N6EZA.png

Comment: note if you have cellTemplates applied (e.g. 12345 -> 12,345) the data returned with this is [the data without that formatting](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/3597) applied

Comment: @Jesper is right. When using pagination, getVisibleRows() only returns the rows of the current page