# UI Grid get sorted items with pagination

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-ui-grid

I have checked all stackoverflow posts related to ui-grid [sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273686/how-to-access-the-sorted-rows-in-an-angular-ui-grid) [rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33432159/angularjs-ui-grid-get-filtered-rows-in-despite-of-pagination) without any success so I am opening one more question.

**SHORT** : Need a way to get sorted rows following current sorting criteria.

My problem is that I have an instance of UI Grid with pagination and I can not get the sorted data after it was added using a `$mdDialog` modal. It is shown at the right position in the tabel, but behind, in all objects it is stored the new element is on the last position.

I call the ui-grid instance using a service to keep all stuff in one place:

```
// Default service for init a ui-grid instance
app.serivce('testService', function(){
  var defaultGridOptions = {
      enableColumnMenus: false,
      enablePaginationControls: true,
      paginationPageSizes: [5],
      multipleSorting: false,
      treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible: false,
      paginationPageSize: 5,
      enableHorizontalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
      enableVerticalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER
  };

  // Each columns sort rule
  // Position 0 from columnsOrder sorts position 0 from columnDefs and so on
  var defaultColSort = [{
      sort: { direction: uiGridConstants.ASC, priority: 0 }
  }];

  this.createGridOptions = function (gridData, columnDefs, gridOpts) {
      gridOpts = typeof gridOpts !== 'undefined' ? gridOpts : {};
      var gridOptions = angular.extend({}, defaultGridOptions, gridOpts);

      for(var i = 0; i < defaultColSort.length; i++)
          columnDefs[i] = angular.extend({}, defaultColSort[i], columnDefs[i]);

      gridOptions.data = gridData;
      gridOptions.columnDefs = columnDefs;
      return gridOptions;
  };


  // The metod that should move to the desired page
  this.jumpToGridItem = function(api, entry) {
      var idx = -1;
      var page = 0;
      var sortedData = null;

      // NEED A WAY TO GET SORTED DATA HERE 
      //idx = sortedData.indexOf(entry); -> checks the position of the new added item

      if (idx == -1)
          return false;

      // Calculate the page where the element exists
      page = Math.ceil(idx/api.grid.options.paginationPageSize);

      // Jump to page
      api.pagination.seek(page);
  };
})
```

Here is my controller :

```
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$mdDialog', 'testService', function($scope, $mdDialog, testService){
  var columnDefs = [
      {
          field: 'identifier',
          name: 'Identifier'
      }
  ];

  var dummyData = [{ identifier: "Item" }, { identifier: 'Item 1' }, { identifier: "Item 2" }, { identifier: "Item 3" }];

  var gridOptions = $scope.gridOptions = testService.createGridOptions(dummyData, columnDefs);

  gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  };

  $scope.add = function () {
      $mdDialog.show({
          controller: function($mdDialog) {
            var data = $scope.identifierVal;
            $mdDialog.hide(data);
          },
          templateUrl: 'add.html',
          parent: angular.element(document.body)
      }).then(function (entry) {
          // Data received when the modal is hidden
          $scope.gridOptions.data.push(entry);
          testService.jumpToGridItem($scope.gridApi, entry);
      });
  };

}]);
```

Right now I am appending the data with `push()`, this could be one reason, I think.

The method I have to update is `jumpToGridItem`, which actually should focus the page where the item was added.

Thank you

PS : Sorry for not posting a plnkr, I will do bit later if it is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to achieve what I initially wanted. I ve found it a day after posting the question but I was busy enough to post the answer. The code below can be also found in a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cYNpEQNTeaAlCqWVPJoV?p=preview). It looks for a certain entry and goes to the page where it can be found.

I wanted this to focus a dynamically added entry in a ui-grid table from a dialog (modal form):

**Controller :**

```
var app = angular.module('stefanz', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'UIGridCustom', '$http', function($scope, UIGridCustom, $http){
  // A part of data copied from ui-grid demos 
  var data = [{"name": "Ethel Price", "gender": "female", "company": "Enersol" },{"name": "Claudine Neal", "gender": "female", "company": "Sealoud" },{"name": "Beryl Rice", "gender": "female", "company": "Velity" },{"name": "Wilder Gonzales", "gender": "male", "company": "Geekko" },{"name": "Georgina Schultz", "gender": "female", "company": "Suretech" },{"name": "Carroll Buchanan", "gender": "male", "company": "Ecosys" },{"name": "Valarie Atkinson", "gender": "female", "company": "Hopeli" },{"name": "Schroeder Mathews", "gender": "male", "company": "Polarium" },{"name": "Lynda Mendoza", "gender": "female", "company": "Dogspa" },{"name": "Sarah Massey", "gender": "female", "company": "Bisba" },{"name": "Robles Boyle", "gender": "male", "company": "Comtract" },{"name": "Evans Hickman", "gender": "male", "company": "Parleynet" },{"name": "Dawson Barber", "gender": "male", "company": "Dymi" }];
  var colDefs = [{
    label: "name",
    name: "name"
  }, {
    label: "gender",
    name: "gender"
  }, {
    label: "company",
    name: "company"
  }];

  // Call the service for init
  var gridOptions = $scope.gridOptions = UIGridCustom.createGridOptions(data, colDefs); 

  gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(api) {
    $scope.gridApi = api;
  }

  $scope.getItemPage = function(name) {
    UIGridCustom.jumpToGridItem($scope.gridApi, name); 
  }

}]);


app.service('UIGridCustom', ['uiGridConstants', 'utils', function(uiGridConstants, utils){
        var defaultGridOptions = {
            enableColumnMenus: false,
            enableHorizontalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
            enableVerticalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
            enablePaginationControls: false,
            paginationPageSize: 5,
            multipleSorting: true
        };

        // Each columns sort rule
        // Position 0 from columnsOrder sorts position 0 from columnDefs and so on
        // Could be overwritten into columnDefs
        // Docs : http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions
        var defaultColSort = [];

        //1st column default sorting
        defaultColSort[{
            sort: { direction: uiGridConstants.ASC, priority: 0 }
        }];

        // For sorting 2nd column
        // defaultColSort[1] = {
        //     sort: { direction: uiGridConstants.ASC, priority: 0 }
        // };


        this.createGridOptions = function (gridData, columnDefs, stefanzGridOpts) {
            // Overwrite defaults with custom passed options for grid
            var stefanzGridOpts = typeof stefanzGridOpts !== 'undefined' ? stefanzGridOpts : {};
            var gridOptions = angular.extend({}, defaultGridOptions, stefanzGridOpts);

            // Force sorting following the default/custom column sort
            for(var i = 0; i < defaultColSort.length; i++)
                columnDefs[i] = angular.extend({}, defaultColSort[i], columnDefs[i]);

            // Grid init
            gridOptions.data = gridData;
            gridOptions.columnDefs = columnDefs;
            return gridOptions;
        };


        this.jumpToGridItem = function(api, name) {
            var idx = 0;
            var page = 0;

            var sorting = prepareCriteria(api.grid.getColumnSorting());
            var data = dataObjectSort(prepareRows(api.grid.rows), sorting);

            entry = getEntryByName(data, name);
            idx = data.indexOf(entry) + 1;

            if (!idx)
                return false;


            // Calculate the page where the element exists
            page = Math.ceil(idx/api.grid.options.paginationPageSize);

            alert(name + 'is found on page ' + page);
            // Jump to page
            api.pagination.seek(page);

        };

        // Takes the row's entity and put in a new array as a top-level item
        // Userful for further data handling 
        var prepareRows = function(rows) {
            if (rows.length == 0)
                return false;

            var preparedRows = [];
            rows.forEach(function(row){
                // Do not need to handle the rows that are not in current filter (hidden)
                if (row.visible == false)
                    return true;

                preparedRows.push(row.entity);
            });
            return preparedRows;
        };

        // We are comparing whole enter and as a parameter we are sending a name
        var getEntryByName = function(data, searchedName) {
          for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i]['name'] == searchedName)
              return data[i];
          }

          return false;
        }

        var dataObjectSort = function(data, criteria) {
            return data.sort(utils.dynamicSortMultiple(criteria));
        };

        var prepareCriteria = function(colSorting) {
            var sorting = [];
            var fields = [];

            // Take just needed fields
            colSorting.forEach(function(column){
                sorting.push({
                    field: column.field,
                    direction: column.sort.direction,
                    priority: column.sort.priority
                })
            });

            // Sort criterias by priority - UI grid works like this
            // Reason : http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef#properties_sort
            sorting.sort(function(a, b){
              if (a.priority < b.priority) return -1;
              else if (a.priority > b.priority) return 1;
              else return 0;
            });

            // Prepare fields for sorting 
            sorting.forEach(function(sort){
                // Dymanic sort (above) needs "-" sign for descendent direction
                if (sort.direction != uiGridConstants.ASC)
                    sort.field = '-' + sort.field;
                fields.push(sort.field);
            });

            return fields;
        };
}]);

// Keep utils methods into a separate service
// Here all sorting methods will appear
app.service('utils', function(){

    function getJsonValue(obj, path) {
        if (!path || path == '') 
            return obj;

        path = path.split('.');

        var len = path.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
            var prop = path[i].split(/\[([^\]]+)]/); // indication[4] => [indication, 4]; indication => [indication]

            if (prop.length == 1) {
                obj = obj[prop[0]];
            } else {
                obj = obj[prop[0]][prop[1]];
            }
        }

        var prop = path[len - 1].split(/\[([^\]]+)]/); // indication[4] => [indication, 4]; indication => [indication]
        if (prop.length == 1) {
            return obj[prop[0]];
        } else {
            if (prop.length == 2) {
                return obj[prop[0]][prop[1]];
            } else {
                if(prop.length ==3) {
                    return obj[prop[0]][prop[1]]; // this is a hack!
                } else {
                    return obj[prop[0]][prop[1]][prop[3]]; // this is a hack!
                }
            }
        }
    };

    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript/4760279#4760279
    function dynamicSort(property) {
        var sortOrder = 1;
        if(property[0] === "-") {
            sortOrder = -1;
            property = property.substr(1);
        }
        return function (a,b) {
            var aInsensitive = getJsonValue(a, property).toLowerCase();
            var bInsensitive = getJsonValue(b, property).toLowerCase();
            var result = (aInsensitive < bInsensitive) ? -1 : (aInsensitive > bInsensitive) ? 1 : 0;
            return result * sortOrder;
        }
    };

    function dynamicSortMultiple(props) {
        return function (obj1, obj2) {
            var i = 0, result = 0, numberOfProperties = props.length;
            while(result === 0 && i < numberOfProperties) {
                result = dynamicSort(props[i])(obj1, obj2);
                i++;
            }
            return result;
        }
    };

    return {
        getJsonValue: function(obj, path) {
            return getJsonValue(obj, path);
        },
        dynamicSort: function(property) {
            return dynamicSort(property);
        },
        dynamicSortMultiple: function(props) {
            return dynamicSortMultiple(props);
        }
    }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="stefanz">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs_1_3_15@*" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angularjs_1_3_15@*" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angularjs_1_3_15@*" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <link data-require="ui-grid@*" data-semver="3.0.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/3.0.7/ui-grid.css" />
    <script data-require="ui-grid@*" data-semver="3.0.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/3.0.7/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@~3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination class="grid"></div>

      <div class="centerAlignedText">
        <ul>
          <li><a ng-click="getItemPage('Ethel Price')">Get Ethel Price</a></li>
          <li><a ng-click="getItemPage('Schroeder Mathews')">Get Schroeder Mathews</a></li>
          <li><a ng-click="getItemPage('Dawson Barber')">Get Dawson Barber</a></li>
          <li><a ng-click="getItemPage('Sarah Massey')">Get Sarah Massey</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>


      <div class="centerAlignedText" ng-if="gridOptions.totalItems > 0">
          <div class="paginationButtonsIcon boldText" style="width: 100px; display: inline-block;">
              <md-button ng-if="gridApi.pagination.getPage() > 1" class="paginationButtons" ng-click="gridApi.pagination.previousPage()" style="width: 90px;">
                  <span class="notTransformedText boldText">Previous</span>
              </md-button>
          </div>
          <div ng-repeat="n in gridApi.pagination.getTotalPages()" style="display: inline-block;">
              <md-button ng-if="(gridApi.pagination.getTotalPages() < 11)
                                || (gridApi.pagination.getPage() < 7 && n < 10)
                                || (n > gridApi.pagination.getPage() - 7 && n < gridApi.pagination.getPage() + 4) 
                                || (gridApi.pagination.getPage() > gridApi.pagination.getTotalPages() - 5 && n > gridApi.pagination.getTotalPages() - 11)" class="paginationButtons md-mini md-icon-button md-primary" ng-click="gridApi.pagination.seek($index + 1)">
                  <span class="paginationButtonsIcon boldText" ng-if="gridApi.pagination.getPage() === $index + 1">
                      {{$index + 1}}
                  </span>
                  <span class="paginationButtonsIcon" ng-if="gridApi.pagination.getPage() !== $index + 1">
                      {{$index + 1}}
                  </span>
              </md-button>
          </div>
          <div class="paginationButtonsIcon boldText" style="width: 100px; display: inline-block;">
              <md-button ng-if="gridApi.pagination.getPage() < gridApi.pagination.getTotalPages()" class="paginationButtons md-icon-button md-primary" ng-click="gridApi.pagination.nextPage()" style="width: 90px;">
                  <span class="notTransformedText boldText">Next</span>
              </md-button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```